# Add comment to Jenkin's plugins.txt

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to add comments to your plugins.txt, eg:

```
email-ext:2.62 //needed for Emailing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is! Accoridng to the [install-plugins.sh file in jenkin's docker repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh#L194), one can simply add a comment using the # sign:

```
email-ext:2.62 #needed for emailing
```